# Why does selecting an option on lightning:combobox not actually select anything?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-combobox

I am using several `lightning:combobox` components on a form and notice that whenever I specify a field (e.g. `value="{!v.contactFields.Gender__c}"`) for its value, it does not select the option I choose.

But if I exclude the `value` attribute or specify a blank value (`value=""`), the option I selected is selected.

I don't have any `onchange` handlers causing the problem, as was the case in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225336/lightning-combobox-sometimes-is-not-selecting-option-selected).

This works:

```
<lightning:combobox name="gender" label="Gender" value="" placeholder="Select Gender" />
```

This does not work:

```
<lightning:combobox name="gender" label="Gender" value="{!v.contactFields.Gender__c}" placeholder="Select Gender" options="{! v.genderOptions }" />
```

I am also using the `force:recordData` component:

```
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" />
<aura:attribute name="contactFields" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="contactCreateError" type="String"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.contact}"
                  targetFields="{!v.contactFields}"
                  targetError="{!v.contactCreateError}" />
```

I followed the record create pattern defined in the `force:recordData` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm). In their example, the individual component values are bound to the `targetFields` attribute of the `force:recordData` component, not the `targetRecord`, so my code does the same thing.

If I bind the control to the `targetRecord` field attribute, like so, it works:

```
<lightning:combobox name="gender" label="Gender" value="{!v.contact.Gender__c}" placeholder="Select Gender" options="{! v.genderOptions }" />
```

However, binding to the `targetFields` field attribute does not work, as I indicated previously:

```
<lightning:combobox name="gender" label="Gender" value="{!v.contactFields.Gender__c}" placeholder="Select Gender" options="{! v.genderOptions }" />
```

Shouldn't I be able to use a field for the combobox value? Or is the proper way to get/set the value is by using Javascript (e.g. `event.getParam("value")`)?

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you shared relevant bits of your code here.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to bind value to a field and have it work correctly. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/f67e2a859667880d8e6b7b2fb47c0e83) that I wrote specifically for you. Ultimately, we're going to need more information/code to help you. I suspect it's probably a combination of two-way bindings that may be causing the problem you're seeing.